# Skill change penalty during a battle

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-console

Changing a skill in my skill set could come in handy when fighting bosses. Can I freely change one in my set of skills to use it during a battle without drawbacks? If not, what are the penalties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update 2.0.3

You can't change a skill:

- during boss battle
- when you are attacked by an ennemy
- while the skill is on cooldown

There are no other restrictions or penalties for changing a skill.

Comment: fyi the cooldown is different based on the difficulty.  Its much harsher on inferno than it is on normal

Comment: @spartacus I did no know that, thanks for the precision

Comment: Please update your answer.  You can't change skills in battle but there is no longer any penalty for swapping active skills anymore.  Passives still have a cooldown